# How do you add an icon to a button_tag using HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, icons, haml

I am having trouble trying to make a play button using HAML.

```
 =button_tag clue_path(@question), class: "btn btn-lg glyphicon glyphicon-play"
```

Results in html

```
<button><icon class:"glyphicon glyphicon-play">/question/1/clue</i></button>
```

It should be

```
<button><icon class: "glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></button>
```

I'm super close to resolving it. What am I missing?

Comment: the button_tag accepts arguments. the first argument is the display-text, where you put in "/questions/1/clue". so the behavior of button_tag is correct. instead go anchor tags, as i described.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking to put an icon inside a button with Bootstrap and HAML, try:

```
%button.btn.btn-lg.btn-default
  %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-play
```

Answer (score 2):

a button tag doenst have a href attribute.

you use a-tags style them like a button.

also i recommend you to use "fontawesome" instead of glyphicon. the integration is super easy, just add the gem and tell bootstrap to use FA.

list of icons is here: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

**for the button do this**

```
=link_to clue_path(@question), class: "btn btn-lg" do 
  %i.glyphicon.glyphicon-play
```

if you are using the font-awesome gem then its just

```
=link_to clue_path(@question), class: "btn btn-lg" do 
  =icon "glyphicon-play"

or

=link_to icon("glyphicon-play"), clue_path(@question), class: "btn btn-lg"
```

Comment: This throws me an error `= link_to "Read more", post_path, class: "btn btn-success btn-lg" do
        =icon("hand-o-right")`
 Any ideas?

Comment: yes. it neads to be `link_to PATH, class: "btn" do BLOCK`

and then in side the block you have "READ MORE" and =icon

its either `link_to text, path, options` OR `link_to path, options, &block`